# using ChangeListener to fire changes in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, changelistener

I am implementing a word guessing game. The attached image gives an idea of what I am doing. My `GamePane` consists of two components, `ControlPane` and `HangManPane`, which is the top and bottom section of the attached image. when the player clicks, `New Game` button, the `GamePane` must be notified. subsequently, the `GamePane` will request the SecretWord from `ControlPane` and pass it on to `HangManPane` to construct the model.

so two things happen here which I would like to know how to implement

1. ControlPane should fire notifications when the user clicks "New Game" button.so this fireChange should happen in the ActionListener of the `New Game` button.
2. `GamePane` listens to the notifications and pass the information to `HangManPane`

Using `ChangeListener` would be appropriate. I did my part of searching, but unable to grasp on how to implement here. Any suggestions are kindly welcome

```
public class GamePane extends JPanel {

    public GamePane(){
         ControlPane cp = new ControlPane();
         //if user clicks New Game on ControlPane, notify me
         //I will then do the following 
         HangManModel model = new DefaultHangManModel(cp.getSecretWord());
         HangManPane hangManPane = new HangManPane(model);

         setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));
         this.add(cp);
         this.add(pane);

    }
 }
```

[image]

Comment: See also `Model#reset()` in this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3072979/230513).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Providing listener support is "relatively" simple.  It's simplified by the fact the `JComponent` exposes it's `EventListenerList` (`listenerList`) as a `protected` variable.

In the `ControlPane`, you'll need an add method...

```
public void addChangeListener(ChangeListener listener) {
    listenerList.add(ChangeListener.class, listener);
}
```

You'll need a remove method

```
public void removeChangeListener(ChangeListener listener) {
    listenerList.remove(ChangeListener.class, listener);
}
```

Now, you need some way to actually raise or fire events as needed...

```
protected void fireStateChanged() {
    ChangeListener[] listeners = listenerList.getListeners(ChangeListener.class);
    if (listeners != null && listeners.length > 0) {
        ChangeEvent evt = new ChangeEvent(evt);
        for (ChangeListener listener : listeners) {
            listener.stateChanged(evt);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, when ever you want to tell registered listeners that the `ControlPane` state has changed, you would simply call `fireStateChanged`, for example...

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    fireStateChanged();
}
```

Now, in the `GamePane`, you will need to register a `ChangeListener` against the instance of the `ControlPane`...

```
private ControlPane cp;
private HangManPane hangManPane;

//...

public GamePane() {
    cp = new ControlPane();
    hangManPane = new HangManPane(null);

    cp.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent evt) {
            String secret = cp.getSecretWord();
            DefaultHangManModel model = new DefaultHangManModel(secret);
            hangManPane.setModel(model);
        }
    });
}
```

For example...

Comment: what is the listenerlist here? and why `ChangeListener[] listeners = listenerList.getListeners(ChangeListener.class);` is needed? I guess there is only one `Listener` I am interested, not a list of them correct?

Comment: now is there way a to fire change to ControlPane from HangManPane once the game is over (either won or lost)

Comment: 1- `listenerList` is, as I said, declared in `JComponent` which is an instance of `EventListenerList`, which is a neat way to maintain a list of a bunch of different listeners, hence 2- `listenerList.getListeners(ChangeListener.class)` returns all the `ChangeListener`s which have being previously registered with the use of `addChangeListener` and you never know who might want to listen in the future ;)...

Comment: 3- What I might do, is when ever `GamePanel` creates a new model, register a `HangManListener` to it, so that when ever the game is lost or won, you would be notified, then I would provide a means by which you could "enable"/"disable" the `ControlPane`...

Comment: I get a compile error 'ChangeEvent evt = new ChangeEvent(evt);`, that is because `evt` variable is not declared..if you dont mind, can you tell line by line what fireStateChanged method does? Thank you very much

Comment: when is this line  `cp.addChangeListener (new ChangeListener() {...` of GamePane is executed? will it execute only if some changes happens in controlPane or is it executed anyway..how then the ControlPane fires back to GamePane when some change occurs..Is `Controlpane` is the controller and `GamePane` the model if we think of `MVC` pattern

Comment: You need to import `ChangeEvent` from the `javax.swing.event` package. `GamePane` should register a `ChangeListener` on `ControlPane` when it constructs an instance of `ControlPane`, presumably within `GamePane`'s constructor. The `ChangeListener` will be notified when ever `ControlPane` executes the `fireStateChanged` method. `GamePane` is an "observer" of `ControlPane`, it is not a model nor is it (really) a controller, it simply observers changes in its state and reacts to them. The `fireStateChanged` method works just like the `fireXxx` methods of the `AbstractHangManModel`

Comment: It look's up all the registered `ChangeListener`s, loop through them and calls the `stateChanged` method, as described by the `ChangeListener` `interface`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41783/discussion-between-user1988876-and-madprogrammer)

Comment: I have put in some code in the chat. somehow the HangManPane is not setting up the model. I need your assistance here. Thanks

Comment: GridBagLayout is now hiding the secret word, I have uploaded the image in chat

Comment: I have some questions posted in chat, can you kindly look at it when you find time